# Can spotipy retrieve the current queue?

Tags: spotify, spotipy

As the title says I would like to get to information on all the tracks currently present in my queue.
Similar to what `current_user_playing_track` but instead of all songs scheduled to play next. I have not been able to find anything in [documentation](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.16.1/) or anything in the [examples](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/tree/master/examples) so I do not know if this is even possible even.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Requesting the user's queue became available in release [2.22.0](https://github.com/spotipy-dev/spotipy/releases/tag/2.22.0) (Dec 10, 2022). [`queue()`](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.22.0/#spotipy.client.Spotify.queue) method is mentioned in spotipy's documentation but with no details. According to the official Spotify's documentation [Get the User's Queue](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-queue) request requires two authorization scopes: `user-read-currently-playing` and `user-read-playback-state`. Successful response contains `currently_playing` (track or episode) and `queue` (list of tracks or episodes). Sample usage:

```py
# spotify = spotipy.Spotify(...)

users_queue = spotify.queue()

currently_playing_track_or_episode = users_queue['currently_playing']
print(f"Currently playing: {currently_playing_track_or_episode['name']}")

for track_or_episode in users_queue['queue']:
    print(f"Queued: {track_or_episode['name']}")
```